# Could we get "n characters left" status when editing "About Me" in our profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, character-limit

Can we get one of those "*n* characters left" statuses when editing "About Me" in our user profile?  This would be similar to the status message you put under comments.

I ask because I hit the character limit, but didn't know that there was one, so my profile got truncated after submission.

Comment: +1 as same happened to me, and I only noticed it much later. Obviously not very urgent FR though.

Comment: yeah, if we had a way of rating how important the FR is, this would be the lowest rating.  i guess the number of upvotes a FR gives would indicate that well enough, i don't see this one getting dozens of votes.

Comment: it's 2000 characters... That's quite a lot of characters to fill up.

Comment: @Alex: Says you.

Comment: Can the limit be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to invoke poetic license and mark this [status-completed] because at least now we *tell* you when the length is exceeded.

(and I increased it to 3000.)

Comment: But the notification error does not mention that the system has trimmed the contents silently. Unfortunately the user does not realize the silent trimming, so if he/she presses the save button immediately or after reducing the contents, the changes will be committed with data loss. I have made my own question for this issue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98611/151752) but before knowing it has been asked here.

Comment: @xport we haven't trimmed contents for a long long time. We simply reject such posts outright with a message.

Comment: Please kindly revisit my link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98611/151752) to see how to reproduce the issue. Shortly speaking, JavaScript trims the excessive contents after the first saving attempt, if we press the Save Profile button immediately or after reducing the contents, the changes will be committed with data loss.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your idea would be nice to have since there is a limit.  But, it is just a little something about yourself, not a resume.

Answer (score 2):

Stop talking about yourself so much?

Comment: Stop writing such long answers. YOU'RE KILLING THE SYSTEM.