# Collection of fun and/or interesting profiles

Tags: discussion, fun, profile-page

I did a few profile related queries. (Only relating to the AboutMe box) and here are some of the interesting profiles I found. Do you know of more fun profiles out there?

**The strange**

- [leeand00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18149)
- [Welbog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443)
- [prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138575)

**The book writers** (People with a long aboutme)

- [yeradis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30715)
- [Joseph Ducreux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4681)
- [kennethfsk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108175)
- [orcmid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33810)

**The people who are trying to break the profile box**

- [x10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140786)
- [Binarytales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319)
- [StfnoPad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16269)

**PGP Keys**

- [erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474)
- [BC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54838)

**Atwood love <3**

- [Sam C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804)
- [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212)

**Just plain fun**

- [Chacha102](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58088)
- [Hooloovoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93246)

**Oddly high profile views**

- [GordonB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66112)
- [geocoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379)

Comment: Welbog fits into all of those subheadings though.

Comment: It's great how great I am.

Comment: You should have a "just plain boring" section. I'd be the first one in it.

Comment: By having a section called "Oddly high profile views," are we not inherently contributing to their status as "oddly high profile views?" :)

Comment: With these guys, it's just a drop in the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Nice finds. Note that all of the texts of the book writers is cut-off. Is that a bug, or did they simply copy/paste those texts without verifying the result?

**Edit**: just tested it: the text is cut off without notice (the maximum number of characters is 2000). Perhaps we should tag this `[bug-report]`?

**Edit 2**: wadda ya know, of course this has already been turned into a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/could-we-get-n-characters-left-status-when-editing-about-me-in-our-profile) over two months ago.

Comment: If it's that long they should just put a link to their I love myself web page

Answer (score 1):

Sneakers O'Toole - https://serverfault.com/users/21

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/10/sneakers-otoole http://superuser.com/users/5172/sneakers-otoole http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132738/sneakers-otoole

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren is the other test account

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mql-cGdNEpQ