# Buggy Length Limit in About Me

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Today, I decided to fill in my "About Me" page with links to my best answers.

However, I hit the 2,000 character limit and *completely* broke my [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34397/horribly-broken).

I assume that this is the column size in the SQL table.
Can it be changed to `ntext`?

## EDIT

The community has asked... *and **I** have answered!*
[Freehand Circle! http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/674/fancierprofilebug.png
Click to view full-size](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/674/fancierprofilebug.png)

Comment: This bug is obvious enough that it doesn't need a freehand circle.

Comment: You can never have too many freehand circles

Comment: If this comment gets ten great-comment votes, I'll add a free-hand circle.

Comment: 7 more to go.  Viva free-hand circles.  And other extraneous things drawn in there.

Comment: Here you go.  Can you fix the bug now?

Comment: Interesting how it affects different browsers in such different manners

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12093, "Could we get “n characters left” status when editing “About Me” in our profile?"

Comment: -1 for not using a red freehand circle.  bad SLaks! bad!

Comment: I shortened my description in SO.  You can still see the bug in my [meta profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34397/horribly-broken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this was crappy. Sorry.

Not sure how we haven't addressed this one better by now.

I increased the limit to 3000 characters and added a check on save to make sure you don't go over; it'll tell you the limit and how many characters you have.

I also fixed the order of HTML sanitization, which has to be done *after* truncation not *before*.

Comment: Can you also allow Markdown?

Answer (score 13):

That's it - let's up the ante:

[Captain Obvious http://www.41085.org/slaks-better.png](http://www.41085.org/slaks-better.png)

Comment: Hey! How dare you post within a minute of me with such a shameful lack of effort!

Comment: Ooooh, free-hand circle with a drop-shadow.  +1

Comment: @json, I'll have you know I put in a lot of effort. I accidentally drew the first freehand circle on the same layer as the screenshot, so I couldn't add the drop shadow.

Comment: +1 for an awesome freehand circle

Comment: +1 for abusing stock Photoshop filters

Comment: Is that Paint.Net? Doesn't look like GIMP work to me... Scratch that. Photoshop.
Make the shadow of the free hand circle work correctly according to physics with the lights, and you get an upvote!

Comment: Yeah, those lens flares are cookie-cutter Photoshop.

Comment: Sampson's gonna get in here and throw it down on you two.

Comment: I must admit, the lens flair filter has improved markedly since Photoshop 5

Comment: I see we have plenty of computer programmers with a readily accessible version of Photoshop.

Comment: @Far: true dat.  Even since Photoshop 7.

Comment: @Chacha, actually I'm a sysadmin, so I really don't know why I've got a copy of Photoshop...

Comment: @Chacha: The first thing I do when on a fresh OS is `sudo pacman -Sy vim svn git openoffice gimp nvidia-driver kde lyx amarok eclipse firefox`.

Comment: wow. just.. wow.

Answer (score 2):

[That's some bug you've got there! http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8505/bugur.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8505/bugur.png)
<sub><del>Left some whitespace for UFOs and llamas to be added.</del>Sparkles added for added shame.</sub>

Comment: Disgustingly good mouse-manship, but no circle... *sigh*

Comment: -1 no freehand circle

Comment: oohhh lense flairs!

Comment: Ok, now it's +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce that too, take a look my [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/s-mark) here on meta.

Comment: That's nothing; look at [mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)!  `<h1>` FTW!

Comment: heh, my eyes !!!