# User page on meta is shifted

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Uh, what happened here?

[S. Mark, user page shift http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/5419/smark.gif](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/5419/smark.gif)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47320/buggy-length-limit-in-about-me

Comment: @ccornet Definitely related. I just hadn't seen it before.

Comment: also related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its related to SLaks's [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47320/buggy-length-limit-in-about-me/47327#47327), just reproduced it but by using `&nbsp;`

Database try to cut it in the middle of `<a href="http://...` tag because of character limit and it made my profile like that :P

Comment: And you prefer it this way? :-)

Comment: @Josh, Not really, just like to test those things out. And actually, when I browse my profile, its not like that. there is one block called *last activity status*, that one got eaten, my profile page is not shifted to right for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this was crappy. Sorry.

Not sure how we haven't addressed this one better by now.

I increased the limit to 3000 characters and added a check on save to make sure you don't go over; it'll tell you the limit and how many characters you have.