# Formatting was messed up in user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User page on meta is shifted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49164/user-page-on-meta-is-shifted)

When I saw user profile of user [S.Mark](https://web.archive.org/web/20100629230721/http://meta.stackoverflow.com:80/users/139541/s-mark) it was not displayed properly. I visited that page more than one time but still it was looking the same. I am adding a screenshot of it.

[image]

Comment: Yea, it seems to be broken for me too

Comment: I think I should update my profile page soon :D

Comment: @S.Mark : Will it be all right if you update it?? What will you update in your profile? And yes..one more thing.. the question you saw as dup is tagged as status-completed but its not completed yet...

Comment: there **was** incomplete quote in near end of my profile about page, that eaten closing table tag and some div around there, so UI is broken. and yes it is completed in system as input validation, but my profile page is already in db, so its like that, now I think Jeff update profile for me, so that partial part of the tags are gone.