# Pressing Save Profile button should not trim the excessive characters at the bottom

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

User Profile only accepts 3000 characters in total.
But the current feature looks so dangerous.
If we attempt to submit more than 3000 characters, *JavaScript* trims the excessive character at the bottom silently. These excessive characters are mostly parts of URLs.

After reading the error message, most people will reduce their contents to do the subsequent attempt. Unfortunately they don't realize their contents have been trimmed by *JavaScript* at the bottom so the subsequent attempt will commit the changes successfully with data loss.

---

Update:

To avoid misunderstanding because of my bad English expression, so I visualize the steps to reproduce the issue as follows.

### Condition right after pressing Edit button

- **Top**
  [image]
- **Bottom**
  [image]

### Adding a dummy lengthy text to the top contents

[image]

### Condition right after pressing Save Profile button

- **Error Message**
  [image]
- **Bottom**
  [image]

### Conclusion

- Most users don't realize that their contents have been trimmed silently by JavaScript, so if they press the save button immediately or after reducing the contents, the changes will be committed with data loss.
- The only way to avoid data loss is by cancelling the changes.

It is my experience that has been tested. I don't know whether you have the same experience.

Comment: +1 if you're asking for the newly-rendered form to show the entire contents, _not_ if you're asking for the whole thing to be stored in the backend anyway... But perhaps the field should provide a character counter similar to the comment-box character counter?

Comment: Is this problem a regression of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/could-we-get-n-characters-left-status-when-editing-about-me-in-our-profile)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is complete next deploy - as you would hope, if something is incorrect no changes are made (your incomplete edit is preserved and redisplayed in it's invalid state, for you to fix).